# PyBind11 function argument is a base class pointer - if I pass a derived class it tells me it's an unsupported type

Tags: python, function, inheritance, pybind11

A function definition that takes a base class does not recognize the derived class as a valid argument when wrapped with pybind11. In pybind11 I have definitions

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass() {}
    virtual void someFunc() { cout << "base\n"; }
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
    DerivedClass() {}
    void someFunc() override { cout << "derived\n"; }
};

class OtherClass
{
public:
    OtherClass() {}
    void someCall(BaseClass *other)
    {
        other->someFunc();
    }
};
```

The bindings like this

```
 PYBIND11_MODULE(solver, m)
    {
        // Experiment
        py::class_<BaseClass>(m, "BaseClass").def(py::init()).def("someFunc", &BaseClass::someFunc);
        py::class_<DerivedClass>(m, "DerivedClass").def(py::init()).def("someFunc", &DerivedClass::someFunc);
        py::class_<OtherClass>(m, "OtherClass").def(py::init()).def("someCall", &OtherClass::someCall);
```

and the python looks like this

```
dc = DerivedClass()
oc = OtherClass()
oc.someCall(dc)
```

I get the error

```
E       TypeError: someCall(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
E           1. (self: solver.OtherClass, arg0: solver.BaseClass) -> None
E
E       Invoked with: <solver.OtherClass object at 0x000001DB1C992530>, <solver.DerivedClass object at 0x000001DB1C992170>
```

How do I make this work so that DerivedClass works with this function call? Thanks for any help!

Comment: How did you wrap your classes? It looks like they might come from two different modules which can create problems (pybind11 employs some peculiar linking strategies)

Comment: they both belong to the same module, but I'm importing them separately ```from somemodule import DerivedClass, OtherClass```

Comment: Pretty weird that one is printed with `solver` and the other with `pygsolver`. Please add the actual pybind11 code, there could be problems there as well.

Comment: Sorry, I had manually changed that name when posting. But yes, everything is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to include the base class in the derived class definition

```
py::class_<DerivedClass, BaseClass>(m, "DerivedClass").def(py::init()).def("someFunc", &DerivedClass::someFunc);
```